# How to add text after div using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to add a line of text after an `h3` tag.

My starting HTML is this:

```
<h3>hi</h3>
```

with no other tags, or document types. I want my ending HTML to look like this:

```
<h3>hi</h3>
{% include 'tester-credit-button' %}
```

I tried the following:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("my_page.html")
title = page.at_css("h3")
#tried this first
title.children.after("\n{% include 'tester-credit-button' %}")

#then this
title << "\n{% include 'tester-credit-button' %}"

#then this
title.after("\n{% include 'tester-credit-button' %}")

#then this
text_node = Nokogiri::XML::Text.new("\n{% include 'tester-credit-button' %}"
, page)
title.add_child(text_node)
```

Answer (score -2):

You're making it much too hard:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<h3>hi</h3>')
doc.at('h3').next = "\n{% include 'tester-credit-button' %}"
puts doc.to_html

# >> <h3>hi</h3>
# >> {% include 'tester-credit-button' %}
```

Back to your code...

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("my_page.html")
```

is wrong. You can test that easily using:

```
page.to_html # => "my_page.html"
```

In [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/DocumentFragment#parse-class_method), when it says "`tags`" it means you have to pass in some HTML or XML:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<p><span>foo</span></p>")
page.to_html # => "<p><span>foo</span></p>"
```

I recommend studying how HTML and XML are structured because your experiments suggest you don't understand the idea of a parsed document's nodes, their possible types, and their children and siblings. Nokogiri's tutorials will help, as will searching for the tag here on SO and reading the various questions and answers. Nokogiri's powerful and easy to use once you get that concept under your belt.

Comment: Nothing to do with the structure of my HTML, nodes or nodesets. Thank you though for suggesting that.